# Force internet traffic over LAN, but connect to router over WiFi

Tags: debian, ethernet, router

This is going to seem like an odd request, but it's necessary. I have a wireless router that is **not** to be used for internet access. The current router that I have is a DLink DIR-626L and I use it to connect to a few embedded devices for an application that I am working on.

For internet, I am hardwired by ethernet into the network. The problem that I am having is that if I connect to my DLink WiFi router, internet traffic wants to go through the DLink router instead over the ethernet port and the DLink router has no internet connection. I know this is going on because if I try to pull up a webpage I get a D-Link error page saying that I am not connected to the internet.

Looking at some other questions, it seems like my router might be advertising itself as a "gateway" and I can't seem to find a way to turn that off by digging through the settings.

Is there a way to tell Linux that all internet traffic should go over the ethernet port?

A few specifications:

-All of the devices that are broadcasting to the router are doing so over UDP. 
They are just spitting out data to a static IP over a dedicated port.

-I am using Linux Mint 17.2.

-I had this setup working with a small battery powered TP-Link router (TL-MR3040). I didn't do anything special for this, it just "worked."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is configure your dhcp client to ignore the router attribute that comes in the DHCP reply.

Edit your /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf that defines which atributes you receive via dhcp, and take out from the line that starts with request the word routers.

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset; # routers;
```

After editing, do

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's what I tried and I'm having the same issue:

`request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, #routers,
 domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
 dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
 netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
 rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
 dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;`
where routers is the end of a line. I should note that my wired internet goes through a different router. I basically want to turn off internet access over WiFi.

Comment: "sudo service networking restart" please

Comment: I rebooted the computer. I couldn't run "sudo service networking restart" beacuse it was saying "Job failed while stopping." However, I did use "sudo service network-manager restart" which would go through. In either respect, I did reboot the computer to load the new config file.

Is there a way to turn off the router as a gateway?

Comment: yes, deleting the route...

Comment: I had to comment out everything past "routers" and not just routers. It appears to be working now. Thank you.

Comment: it is also rfc3442-classless-static-routes most probably